# Siganlr Crank load testing tool batch size parameter

Tags: signalr

What is batchsize parameter in SignalR Crank load testing tool?

Also please help me to understand what the function "connectbatch" is doing? As per my understanding  it just creates a n client connections based on input parameter "clients"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BatchSize is used to define the number of connections that are created in one batch.
Once the batch size is reached Crank waits for a successful connection for all created clients before it moves on.

Crank (and signalR in general) lean heavily on TPL and async/await. This enables a large number of requests to be created in one batch